# In Python, how do I call the super class when it's a one-off namedtuple?

Tags: inheritance, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super, namedtuple

So, I have a large number of message Payload classes for a serial API, each of which has a number of immutable fields, a parse method, and some methods which are shared. The way I'm structuring this is that each will inherit from a namedtuple for the field behaviours, and receive the common methods from a parent class. However, I'm having some difficulties with the constructors:

```
class Payload:
    def test(self):
        print("bar")

class DifferentialSpeed(Payload, namedtuple('DifferentialSpeed_', 
    'left_speed right_speed left_accel right_accel')):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # TODO: Field verification
        print("foo")

    @classmethod
    def parse(self, raw):
        # Dummy for now
        return self(left_speed = 0.0, right_speed = 0.1,
                    left_accel = 0.2, right_accel = 0.3)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Left Speed: %fm/s\nRight Speed: %fm/s\n"\
            "Left Acceleration: %fm/s^2\nRight Acceleration: %fm/s^2" % (
            self.left_speed, self.right_speed, self.left_accel, self.right_accel)


payload = DifferentialSpeed.parse('dummy')
print(payload)
```

This works, but I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters
  super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

If I remove `**kwargs` from the call, it still seems to work, but why? How are those arguments to the constructor getting passed through to the namedtuple? Is this guaranteed, or a random result of how the **mro** gets established?

If I wanted to stay away from super, and do it the old way, is there some way I can access the namedtuple to call its constructor? I'd rather not have to do this:

```
DifferentialSpeed_ = namedtuple('DifferentialSpeed_', 
    'left_speed right_speed left_accel right_accel')
class DifferentialSpeed(Payload, DifferentialSpeed_):
```

Seems kind of verbose and unnecessary.

What's my best course of action here?

Comment: Note that if you're trying to use `namedtuple` to save memory, you need to set `__slots__ = ()` in the derived class as well as the other inherited `Payload` class, or the class will still have a `__dict__`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For starters, `namedtuple(whatever)` inherits from `tuple`, which is immutable, and immutable types don't bother with `__init__`, because by the time `__init__` is called the object is already constructed. If you want to pass arguments to the `namedtuple` base class you'll have to override `__new__` instead.

You can see the definition of the result of `namedtuple()` by passing in a `verbose=true` argument; I find it educational.

Comment: Oh, okay. Very interesting. It doesn't matter to me about passing things to the namedtuple; I just wanted to make sure it wasn't going to miss out on its arguments. Perhaps I can just ignore the whole super() problem altogether.

Comment: All right, gonna accept this one, for being helpful and brief. I think in the end, I'll probably go with a common constructor in Payload, which calls a polymorphic "self.verify()", which can then throw exceptions as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You have three base classes: `Payload`, your namedtuple `DifferentialSpeed_`, and the common base class `object`.  Neither of the first two have an `__init__` function at all, except for the one inherited from `object`.  `namedtuple` doesn't need an `__init__`, since the initialization of immutable classes is done by `__new__`, which is called before `__init__` is run.

Since `super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__` resolves to the next `__init__` in the call chain, the next `__init__` is `object.__init__`, which means you're passing arguments to that function.  It doesn't expect any--there's no reason to be passing arguments to `object.__init__`.

(It used to accept and silently ignore arguments.  That behavior is going away--it's gone in Python 3--which is why you get a DeprecationWarning.)

You can trigger the problem more clearly by adding a `Payload.__init__` function that takes no arguments.  When you try to pass along `**kwargs*, it'll raise an error.

The correct thing to do in this case is almost certainly to remove the `**kwargs` argument, and just call `super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__()`.  It doesn't take any arguments; `DifferentialSpeed` is passing `Payload` its *own* arguments that `Payload`, and functions further down the call chain, know nothing about.

Comment: Your statement "The correct thing to do in this case is almost certainly to remove the `**kwargs` argument, and just call `super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__(**kwargs)`" seems contradictory, shouldn't the last part be "just call `super(DifferentialSpeed, self).__init__()`"?

Comment: In case anyone else gets here, note that there's another reason involved in this warning showing up or not; see the comment about `__new__` in Objects/typeobject.c.  (I don't feel like going into detail, since the OP ignored this answer completely and accepted one that didn't even answer his question...)

Comment: Thanks for the correction and clarification. Perhaps the OP ignored your answer because it didn't entirely make sense. Regardless, the rules about when `__new__()` produces warnings about arguments are indeed complicated. For anyone interested, you can see a copy of just the relevant comment from `typecobject.c` [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/typeobject.c_excerpt.txt) or the entire source file in svn [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/typeobject.c?revision=81744&view=markup).

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed-out, tuples are an immutable type, which must be initialized in their `__new__()` instead of their `__init__()` method -- so you need to add the former in your subclass (and get rid of the latter). Below is how this would be applied to your example code. The only other change was adding a `from import...` statement to the beginning.

**Note:** `cls` has to be passed twice in the `super()` call in `__new__()` because it's a static method although it is special-cased so you don't have to declare it to be one.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Payload:
    def test(self):
        print("bar")

class DifferentialSpeed(Payload, namedtuple('DifferentialSpeed_',
    'left_speed right_speed left_accel right_accel')):
    #### NOTE: __new__ instead of an __init__ method ####
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        self = super(DifferentialSpeed, cls).__new__(cls, **kwargs)
        # TODO: Field verification
        print("foo")
        return self

    @classmethod
    def parse(self, raw):
        # Dummy for now
        return self(left_speed = 0.0, right_speed = 0.1,
                    left_accel = 0.2, right_accel = 0.3)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Left Speed: %fm/s\nRight Speed: %fm/s\n"\
            "Left Acceleration: %fm/s^2\nRight Acceleration: %fm/s^2" % (
            self.left_speed, self.right_speed, self.left_accel, self.right_accel)


payload = DifferentialSpeed.parse('dummy')
print(payload)
```

Comment: There's no need to touch `__new__`.  He'd only need to do that if he wanted to modify the arguments that `DifferentialSpeed_` is initialized with; he's only verifying them.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Seems to me like `__new__()` *would* need to be involved so the arguments could be verified *before* they were assigned to the tuple (since they can't be be changed later). e.g. They could be given default values or an exception raised without any bogus assignments made.

Comment: Raising an exception from `__init__` works just as well.  (Silently forcing a default doesn't sound like sane behavior.)

Comment: Yes, my intention would be just to raise an exception from __init__. This is actually a bi-directional message payload, so it can be instantiated from parsed data, and also from the constructor directly. The verification is mostly for the benefit of the non-parsed behaviour.